# What is the equivalent of $args[basename($img_path)] = '@' . realpath($img_path); in javascript?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, equivalent

What is the equivalent of the following PHP code done in javascript?

```
$img_path = "test.jpg"; // image located on my server
 $args = array(
'aid'       => $aid,       // album id
'caption'   => $img_caption,    // caption for image
'uid'       => $userid,   // facebook user id of the poster
'format'    => 'json'
);

$args[basename($img_path)] = '@' . realpath($img_path);
```

Comment: please be more specific , tell us what is this code?? for what purpose is it ?? why do you want to do using javascript ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually none, because there is no equivalent of realpath() in javascript. Realpath() needs access to the server's filesystem, whereas javascript is executed on the client side